# If linen armor is really that effective, why was it not used?

Tags: technology, warfare, materials, armors, bronze-age

Looking into possible lines of development of armor in low-tech civilization, I came across this: https://jhupress.wordpress.com/2013/04/24/unraveling-the-linothorax-mystery-or-how-linen-armor-came-to-dominate-our-lives/

Which makes an extraordinary claim:

> ... we still felt compelled to try a real-life scenario, so Scott donned the armor and Greg shot him. And while we had confidence in our armor, our relief was still considerable when the arrowhead stuck and lodged in the armor’s outer layers, a safe distance away from flesh.

> When you wear it for a couple hours, your own body heat softens the glue a bit and makes it conform to your body shape, so it is much more comfortable to wear than rigid types of armor. Our reconstructions weighed about 10 pounds–about one third the weight of bronze armor that would provide the same degree of protection. Thanks for the questions!

So the article is claiming – and not based on speculation or legend, but actual empirical testing – that linen armor is just as effective as bronze armor, weighs one third as much and is more comfortable to wear.

Linen is surely much cheaper than bronze. And while steel is ultimately superior, early iron is not superior to bronze (was only preferred due to the ore being more plentiful than tin).

So the above seems to be implying that linen is superior in every way – cost, practicality, effectiveness – to metal armor.

On the face of it, that means it is a valid substitute in an alternate history setting. My problem is that the above goes much too far, because if it is true, *the history of our world makes no sense whatsoever*. Why would anyone go to all the trouble of inventing metal armor when linen was both better and cheaper?

So what's the catch? What am I missing?

Comment: That doesn't sound like a worldbuilding problem to me. You're just asking about the real world.

Comment: It is and it was, the Greeks used to use stiffened cloth armour, we were still using quilted and cloth armour in the middle ages, we also have anti ballistic materials we use now, a little research might not have gone amiss, metal is better for some things in some circumstances, cloth had its niche, particularly if weight, cost or climate was a consideration, both are better than the other in the right circumstances .. so what are you missing? when it comes to context practically everything 

Comment: this is more a history question than worldbuilding, try the history stack.

Comment: This might be a decent skeptics. question, given the historical nature and potential controversy involved in the details.  If the ancients didn't use glue, how did they do it, and would that be less effective than a glue they had access to?  But the question is also relevant here, because there is a clear goal to propose a world that uses linen armor and ask "what is the catch...?"

Comment: A single layer of linen is cheaper then bronze. A multi layer composite of many layers of linen, with glue, quilting and other processing?  Quite likely that  bronze armor is cheaper.    Modern textiles are absurdly cheap.

Comment: It's called a gambeson and was used ALL THE TIME. If you're poor you wear it alone. If you're rich you wear it under your chainmail or plate armour.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

1. Linen armor is indeed quite effective against lightweight projectiles. It won't do much against heavier weapons, such as spears, which were the main infantry weapon for thousands of years. It is also not very effective against slashing weapons, such as swords.
2. If that "Greg" is [Gregory S. Aldrete](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gregory_S._Aldrete) then please note that his composite linen-and-glue [linothorax](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linothorax) is very different from what was actually used in Ancient Greece. ([His reconstruction](https://en.wikipedia.org/w/index.php?title=Linothorax&oldid=1093581003#Research) was based on a garbled Byzantine text.)
3. Textile and leather armor were used throughout history. Ordinary soldiers wore only a textile gambeson up to the end of the Middle Ages. Well-to-do military men wore a metal armor on the outside, and a textile [arming doublet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gambeson) under it. (Trying to wear only the metal armor is not recommended.)
4. Overall, from the antiquity up to Early Modern times, the armor of choice was always a composite of metal and leather, or metal and textile.

Comment: The big thing is that it doesn't spread out impact nearly as much as something more rigid would.  It may keep a spear from going clear through someone, but won't stop it from breaking ribs, etc.  Whereas rigid armor spreads the force over a much wider area.  There is also a significant durability difference. In the Napoleonic wars, for example, it was often noted that even just a cold-weather wool coat could take most, if not all, of the bite out of a saber slash...  Once.  After that there was a big hole in it.

Comment: @Perkins gambesons were frequently used underneath plate armor precisely because of their ability to help absorbing impacts and the additional layer of protection/padding, especially from the more blunt force weapons that were more effective against plate armor. If anything you're more likely to end with a broken rib if you aren't wearing one, since the impact will be transferred from the armor directly to you with no softer layer of cloth to help redistribute the force and dampen the impact.

Comment: @ProjectApex  Yes, but the gambeson alone without the rigid plate overtop it to spread the impact protects much less against a mace too.  Blunt weapons don't work better against plate because they're blunt, they do better against plate because they generate much higher momentum.  The padding underneath the plate then serves the dual purpose of lengthening the absorption time and compensating for the plate not being a perfect fit.  (which would otherwise result in the impact being applied mostly to only a few points of contact between the plate and the wearer.)

Comment: @Perkins I'm aware of that. Blunt weapons were blunt simply because a truly pointy or sharp weapon would normally be useless against metal armor, easily loosing said point or edge (still many "anti-armor" weapons had blunted "Spikesc precisely to concentrate the force on a smaller area, maximizing the impact of the weapon). The thing is that the gambeson was much better at dealing with such type of damage than the rigid plate armor itself. They did indeed help making the armor a better fit in many cases though. The combination of the two with some chainmail was truly a great match.

Comment: @ProjectApex The gambeson works primarily by increasing the duration of the impact, thereby reducing the peak shock load.  The plate works primarily by spreading the impact over a larger, or at least different, area to protect soft spots.  So the two definitely do pair up rather nicely.  Rigid plates alone with no padding have been in use for a long time as well though, we call them "shields".

Answer (score 6):

**A couple of reasons**

First would be cut resistance. Swords and such cut through the linen fibers, while that'd be much harder to do to any metallic armour(If not wholly impossible with the strength behind a human arm unless it's a particularly soft kind of metal).

The second would be maintenance. If you happen to make a dent or chop a chip or two into metallic armour it's also more easily repaired and a repair would have you end up with a still-reliable piece of armour, while for linen you'll likely need to reweave the whole section due to a simple stitch repair leading to compromised protection.

The third would be social. The material of what something is made of plays a large part in its intimidation and social standing factor. A grown and woven and dull material is cheap and in the eyes of many "peasant-like", while something that had to be mined and cast/forged and shines as a finished product adds quite a lot to how valuable your soldiers are perceived to be both on the battlefield and off it.

Comment: The social angle is important. Not just for enemy intimidation, but for the soldiers morale.

Answer (score 0):

You are forgetting that your troops and your people need to be fed.

Iron ore doesn't compete with grains for cultivable ground, while flax does. So if you grow flax to ensure a supply of linen for your army, you end up starving that same army, because you end up growing less grains. And history teaches us that a starved army is a dangerous army.

Comment: Flax does indeed compete with wheat, sort of. But people still do grow flax and cotton and hemp, anyway. They do like their textiles.

Comment: I don't think this answer deserved to be downvoted; it is true as far as it goes. But while iron *ore* doesn't compete with food production, *iron* does, because each kilogram of iron takes several kilograms of charcoal, which means many kilograms of wood, which means a lot of land needing to be allocated to trees. I think linen actually needs much less arable land when you get down to it.